# FileNotFound Exception in Gmail API

Tags: java

I had coded automation testing for sending email but unfortunately the credential json file cannot be located.

Code:

```
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = ".//credential//credentials.json";


InputStream in = EmailManager.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
```

I put the credentials.json file at the root directory inside credential folder.

PS: Running from /src/test/java/com/rev/testManager

The emailManager located at /src/main/java/com/rev/manager.

[image: Folder structure]

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: From which folder is your java application/service running from? Maybe you want to give absolute path to credentials file instead.

Comment: Please show your folder/package structure of the files in question (esp. for the class `EmailManager` and the file `CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH`).

Comment: Added the required info.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream( CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH );
```

instead of

```
InputStream in = EmailManager.class.getResourceAsStream( CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH );
```

`getResourceAsStream()` creates an `InputStream` for a *resource* – usually a  file – on the CLASSPATH, not on the regular file system.

From the provided 'filename', I assume that you want to read from the file system, so you have to use `FileInputStream` instead. This is confirmed by the provided screen shot.

Comment: Let me try and see.